# Different search results in different environments

Tags: python, pandas, search, ipython, data-science

I am learning Data science and while doing a problem, I came across a weird observation. The problem was to print the number of occurrences of the string 'Soup' on the Beautiful Soup home page, using python. The weird part is, *the number of occurrences varies in the iPython notebook and in Python* and when I ran a manual search on the webpage the *result was entirely different*.

I'd love if someone could give a plausible explanation. I have attached along, the code snippets and the results:

**In Python**

[image: I have simply used urllib and not BeautifulSoup]

**In Pandas**

[image: Using the .count() function]

**Manually**

[image]

As you can see the result varies in all the environments, it shows 39 occurrences in Python, 41 in Pandas and 35 via manual search.

Thanks

Comment: I would always expect a manual search on the site itself would be less as the text you see is a subset of what's in the source.  I can't explain the difference in the other two.  Also, that isn't pandas, that's urllib2 run in jupyter.  @jezrael seems to have nailed the answer.  I'd choose that one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think `Python` found only `39`, because `2` missing are in `<head>`:

```
<title>Beautiful Soup: We called him Tortoise because he taught us.</title>
<meta name="Description" content="Beautiful Soup: a library designed for screen-scraping HTML and XML.">
```

You can check it by [`Source of the page`](https://support.mozilla.org/sk/questions/973832) - there are `41` occurrences.

If check `webpage` manually (35  occurences), 4 are in `urls` and `2` in `<head>`, so together `41`:

```
<a href="http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs3/documentation.html">Here's
the Beautiful Soup 3 documentation.</a>
<a href="download/3.x/BeautifulSoup-3.2.1.tar.gz">3.2.1</a> 
<a href="/source/software/BeautifulSoup/index.bhtml">
<a href="http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/">
```